# Using Widgets and the Base Design Package

Tags: blocks, widgets

When you're setting up a widget instance, Magento asks you to select a Design Package/Theme.  This includes the `base/default` package.

[image]

Why is this here?  Can is be used for anything?  My initial assumption would be this is here to add a widget to **all** themes — but that doesn't appear to work.  Am I incorrect in this and just doing something wrong?

My next assumption is the widget UI was designed to "display all themes", but didn't take into account the special behavior of the base design package.

Can this `base/default` entry be used for anything in a Widget Instance?  Or is it a vestigial feature, present only to confuse us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's there without any working functionality for it. Only if your storeview is actually using that package/theme combination, but not as a default for all themes as you suggest.

In `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Layout` you can find the method `fetchUpdatesByHandle`, which fetches all widget generated layout updates from the database. That query will only fetch the records for the current package, theme and some other params like store_id.

So no it can't be used as a 'for anything' setting. Otherwise there had to be a fallback mechanism in the query to also always include the widgets based on `base/default`.

Comment: +1 — I saw the same thing, but it seems weird that it's stayed in the list for so long. That always makes me wonder if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Haven't we all had that feeling when working w/ Magento ;)

Answer (score 1):

> My initial assumption would be this is here to add a widget to all themes

As of Magento 1.9.3.8, widgets are not inherited from parent theme to child theme. Like you, I would expect them to be inherited.

I am assuming this was a forgotten feature in someone's 'todo' list that never got implemented.

I wanted this feature so I wrote an extension that does this.

Here it is: https://github.com/mpalasis/Palasis_Inheritwidgets